# Permission problem accessing a QuickBooks company data file

Tags: php, quickbooks

I want to add a `.qwc` file to web connector for QuickBooks Premier. This is my log file:

```
Log file initialized at Tuesday, December 17, 2019 - 6:50 PM UTC  
Timestamp format used: YYYYMMDD.HH:MM:SS UTC
QBWebConnector 2.2 has been initialized with its logging status to level = DEBUG.
Please restart QBWebConnector for any change in log level to take effect. Use file menu to clear log.

20191217.18:50:04 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setNotifyWindowOn() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\NotifyWindowOn has been set to False
20191217.18:50:04 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setMaxConnRetries() : Maximum connection retries count has been set to 10
20191217.18:50:04 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20191217.18:50:04 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20191217.18:50:04 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20191217.18:50:04 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20191217.18:50:05 UTC   : QBWebConnector_Load() : 
QuickBooks Web Connector 2.3.0.36 has started.
Tuesday, December 17, 2019 at 1:50:05 PM
20191217.18:50:05 UTC   : QBWebConnector_Load() : QBWC Form Loaded
20191217.18:50:28 UTC   : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: -
<QBWCXML>
  <AppName>Water Ways Decor</AppName>
  <AppID></AppID>
  <AppURL>http://localhost/water_ways/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/web_connector.php</AppURL>
  <AppDescription></AppDescription>
  <AppSupport>https://www.esakal.com/</AppSupport>
  <UserName>quickbooks</UserName>
  <OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A7E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
  <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4fcc-B1FF-967DE1813D21}</FileID>
  <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
  <Scheduler>
    <RunEveryNMinutes>5</RunEveryNMinutes>
  </Scheduler>
  <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
20191217.18:50:28 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : Parsing application configuration xml file to load its content to variables
20191217.18:50:30 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Error creating registry key for appName = <>
20191217.18:50:30 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: name
20191217.18:50:30 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.SerializeToRegistry() : Error saving Water Ways Decor to Registry: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
20191217.18:50:30 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
20191217.18:50:30 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <This application has not accessed this QuickBooks company data file before. The QuickBooks administrator must grant an application permission to access a QuickBooks company data file for the first time.>.
20191217.18:50:30 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : QBWC1039: There was a problem adding the application. Check QWCLog.txt for details.
<Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <This application has not accessed this QuickBooks company data file before. The QuickBooks administrator must grant an application permission to access a QuickBooks company data file for the first time.>.>
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.AddToQuickBooks()
20191217.18:50:48 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.DisconnectFromQB() : QBWC1015: Error closing connection to QuickBooks.
Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: g
20191217.18:57:43 UTC   : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: -
<QBWCXML>
  <AppName>Water Ways Decor</AppName>
  <AppID></AppID>
  <AppURL>http://localhost/water_ways/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/web_connector.php</AppURL>
  <AppDescription></AppDescription>
  <AppSupport>https://www.esakal.com/</AppSupport>
  <UserName>quickbooks</UserName>
  <OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A7E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
  <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4fcc-B1FF-967DE1813D21}</FileID>
  <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
  <Scheduler>
    <RunEveryNMinutes>5</RunEveryNMinutes>
  </Scheduler>
  <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
20191217.18:57:43 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : Parsing application configuration xml file to load its content to variables
20191217.18:57:44 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Error creating registry key for appName = <>
20191217.18:57:44 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: name
20191217.18:57:44 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.SerializeToRegistry() : Error saving Water Ways Decor to Registry: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
20191217.18:57:44 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
20191217.18:57:45 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <This application has not accessed this QuickBooks company data file before. The QuickBooks administrator must grant an application permission to access a QuickBooks company data file for the first time.>.
20191217.18:57:45 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : QBWC1039: There was a problem adding the application. Check QWCLog.txt for details.
<Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <This application has not accessed this QuickBooks company data file before. The QuickBooks administrator must grant an application permission to access a QuickBooks company data file for the first time.>.>
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.AddToQuickBooks()
20191217.18:57:47 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.DisconnectFromQB() : QBWC1015: Error closing connection to QuickBooks.
Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: g
20191217.18:57:48 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20191217.18:57:48 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20191217.18:57:48 UTC   :  : Stopped FlexConnector successfully.


Log file initialized at Wednesday, December 18, 2019 - 3:29 PM UTC  
Timestamp format used: YYYYMMDD.HH:MM:SS UTC
QBWebConnector 2.2 has been initialized with its logging status to level = DEBUG.
Please restart QBWebConnector for any change in log level to take effect. Use file menu to clear log.

20191218.15:29:53 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20191218.15:29:53 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20191218.15:29:53 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Intuit\QBWebConnector\UpdateLock has been set to False
20191218.15:29:53 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.setUpdateLock() : ********************* Update session unlocked *********************
20191218.15:29:53 UTC   : QBWebConnector_Load() : 
QuickBooks Web Connector 2.3.0.36 has started.
Wednesday, December 18, 2019 at 10:29:53 AM
20191218.15:29:53 UTC   : QBWebConnector_Load() : QBWC Form Loaded
20191218.15:30:48 UTC   : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: -
<QBWCXML>
  <AppName>Water Ways Decor</AppName>
  <AppID></AppID>
  <AppURL>http://localhost/water_ways/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/web_connector.php</AppURL>
  <AppDescription></AppDescription>
  <AppSupport>https://www.esakal.com/</AppSupport>
  <UserName>quickbooks</UserName>
  <OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A7E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
  <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4fcc-B1FF-967DE1813D21}</FileID>
  <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
  <Scheduler>
    <RunEveryNMinutes>5</RunEveryNMinutes>
  </Scheduler>
  <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
20191218.15:30:48 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : Parsing application configuration xml file to load its content to variables
20191218.15:30:50 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Error creating registry key for appName = <>
20191218.15:30:50 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: name
20191218.15:30:50 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.SerializeToRegistry() : Error saving Water Ways Decor to Registry: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
20191218.15:30:50 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
20191218.15:30:50 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <This application has not accessed this QuickBooks company data file before. The QuickBooks administrator must grant an application permission to access a QuickBooks company data file for the first time.>.
20191218.15:30:50 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : QBWC1039: There was a problem adding the application. Check QWCLog.txt for details.
<Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <This application has not accessed this QuickBooks company data file before. The QuickBooks administrator must grant an application permission to access a QuickBooks company data file for the first time.>.>
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.AddToQuickBooks()
20191218.15:31:02 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.DisconnectFromQB() : QBWC1015: Error closing connection to QuickBooks.
Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: g
20191218.15:38:39 UTC   : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: -
<QBWCXML>
  <AppName>Water Ways Decor</AppName>
  <AppID></AppID>
  <AppURL>http://192.168.50.11/water_ways/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/web_connector.php</AppURL>
  <AppDescription></AppDescription>
  <AppSupport>http://waterwaysdecor.com/</AppSupport>
  <UserName>quickbooks</UserName>
  <OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A7E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
  <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4fcc-B1FF-967DE1813D21}</FileID>
  <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
  <Scheduler>
    <RunEveryNMinutes>1</RunEveryNMinutes>
  </Scheduler>
  <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
20191218.15:38:39 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : Parsing application configuration xml file to load its content to variables
20191218.15:38:41 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Error creating registry key for appName = <>
20191218.15:38:41 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: name
20191218.15:38:41 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.SerializeToRegistry() : Error saving Water Ways Decor to Registry: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
20191218.15:38:41 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
20191218.15:38:41 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <This application has not accessed this QuickBooks company data file before. The QuickBooks administrator must grant an application permission to access a QuickBooks company data file for the first time.>.
20191218.15:38:41 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : QBWC1039: There was a problem adding the application. Check QWCLog.txt for details.
<Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <This application has not accessed this QuickBooks company data file before. The QuickBooks administrator must grant an application permission to access a QuickBooks company data file for the first time.>.>
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.AddToQuickBooks()
20191218.15:41:11 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.DisconnectFromQB() : QBWC1015: Error closing connection to QuickBooks.
Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: g
20191218.15:42:08 UTC   : QWCReader.ParseQWC() : Contents of QWC file: -
<QBWCXML>
  <AppName>Water Ways Decor</AppName>
  <AppID></AppID>
  <AppURL>http://192.168.50.11/water_ways/quickbooks-php-master/docs/web_connector/web_connector.php</AppURL>
  <AppDescription></AppDescription>
  <AppSupport>http://waterwaysdecor.com/</AppSupport>
  <UserName>quickbooks</UserName>
  <OwnerID>{90A44FB7-33D9-4815-AC85-AC86A7E7D1EB}</OwnerID>
  <FileID>{57F3B9B6-86F1-4fcc-B1FF-967DE1813D21}</FileID>
  <QBType>QBFS</QBType>
  <Scheduler>
    <RunEveryNMinutes>1</RunEveryNMinutes>
  </Scheduler>
  <IsReadOnly>false</IsReadOnly>
</QBWCXML>
20191218.15:42:08 UTC   : QBWebConnector.WebServiceManager.ReadQWC(QWCReader QWC) : Parsing application configuration xml file to load its content to variables
20191218.15:42:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Error creating registry key for appName = <>
20191218.15:42:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.RegistryManager.createRegKey() : Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: name
20191218.15:42:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.SerializeToRegistry() : Error saving Water Ways Decor to Registry: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
20191218.15:42:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Connecting to QuickBooks...
20191218.15:42:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.ConnectToQB() : Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <This application has not accessed this QuickBooks company data file before. The QuickBooks administrator must grant an application permission to access a QuickBooks company data file for the first time.>.
20191218.15:42:10 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.AddToQuickBooks() : QBWC1039: There was a problem adding the application. Check QWCLog.txt for details.
<Error connecting to QuickBooks. Error message received from QuickBooks was <This application has not accessed this QuickBooks company data file before. The QuickBooks administrator must grant an application permission to access a QuickBooks company data file for the first time.>.>
   at QBWebConnector.WebService.AddToQuickBooks()
20191218.15:42:13 UTC   : QBWebConnector.SOAPWebService.DisconnectFromQB() : QBWC1015: Error closing connection to QuickBooks.
Reason: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: g
```

Also, it is showing a popup saying:

> This application has not accessed this QuickBooks company data file
>   before. The QuickBooks administrator must grant an application
>   permission to access a QuickBooks company data file for the first
>   time.

How do I give permission?

Answer (score 0):

You need to be logged in a QuickBooks administrator.

- Log out of QuickBooks.
- Log back in with the `Admin` username
- Re-add the `.QWC` file to the QuickBooks Web Connector

It will prompt you to allow access/give permission.